# Quartus II Memory Read Clock Problem

Tags: clock, memory, ram, quartus-ii

I used LPM_RAM to store data and made read and write operations. But it seems like placing the data to wrong addresses. Here is screenshots;

Wave Result;

[image]

Memory Block;

[image]

Comment: Some of the signals in the "scope" plot I am not seeing in the schematic -- M_ADDR, M_INP and M_OUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's pretty hard to read the diagrams, I can't see the crucial M_ADDR, M_INP and M_OUT on the diagram as I said in the comments, and I know nothing about Quartus II, so I feel ideally qualified to comment...

Looks to me like you have either a stage of latches either in the address path or in the data out path which is causing the displayed output data to be one clock cycle delayed relative to the displayed address.

[image]

So it's not reading data from the wrong address, it's just delayed.

Comment: M_ADDR is ADDR, M_INP is Input and M_OUT is Output. So, can we say that, writing operation takes 1 cycle and reading operation takes 2 cycle?

Comment: You tell me -- I can't really read the diagram. How many latch stages are there in each path between address and the destination of the data?

Comment: Also, there's a distinction to be made between clock cycles per read, versus read latency.

Comment: I don't know how to look inside RAM. Maybe I should read its documentation. What's its relation with latches?

Comment: So, all my operations that needs memory read cannot be done in one clock pulse. Is it true?

Comment: Here's my problem. Knowing nothing about Quartus, I don't really know what functionality the symbols are shorthand for. But in terms of real components, memory is just a latch (aka register). So long as you have it selected for write when the clock arrives, the data gets latched into the memory. If you have it selected for read, it allows its content data onto the bus. In general you don't have to latch the output data in order to read it, so long as the ultimate destination can grab it in time. Maybe you don't need that output latch, and you could see the data one cycle earlier.

Comment: But if that output latch is part of the library component, then maybe you're stuck with it.

Comment: I found this on manual; "Similarly, the second read operation occurs at 65 ns, but the data appears
on the output one cycle later, at 75 ns. This delay is due to registered q
output set with the wizard. If you want to override the delay, use
unregistered q output."

Comment: Looks like your manual backs up my conclusions, and also tells you how to avoid the extra cycle of latency, when that's feasible. Mystery solved! Thanks for letting us know.